# Binding Shapes.Path items to a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have been trying to figure out how to bind an `ObservableCollection<FrameworkElements>` to an ItemsControl. I have an existing project which relies heavily on code behind and canvas's without binding which I am trying to update to use mvvm and prism.

The ObservableCollection is going to be populated with a number of Path items. They are generated from an extermal library which I use. The library functions correctly when I manually manipulate the canvas itself.

Here is a snippet of the code from the ViewModel:

```
    ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> _items;
    ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Supporting XAML

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" IsItemsHost="True">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="100"/>
                        </Canvas.Background>

                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The issue I am experiencing is that the Path's never draw. Any suggestion on where I am going wrong and where to start the debug process?

Comment: The original instance works, I just forgot the `public` when declaring the collection.

Answer (score 2):

Your view model should contain an abstract representation of a Path, e.g.

```
public class PathData
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    public Brush Stroke { get; set; }
    public double StrokeThickness { get; set; }
    // ... probably more Stroke-related properties
}
```

If you now have a collection of PathData objects like

```
public ObservableCollection<PathData> Paths { get; set; }
```

your ItemsControl could have an ItemsTemplate as shown below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Paths}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}" Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                  Stroke="{Binding Stroke}" StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

You would now add PathData instance like this:

```
Paths.Add(new PathData
{
    Geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(100, 100, 100, 100)),
    Fill = Brushes.AliceBlue,
    Stroke = Brushes.Red,
    StrokeThickness = 2
});
```

Comment: You're creating UI in your ViewModel and giving me shit about using path data?  Dude.

Comment: @Will There is no UI in this view model. Just geometries and brushes, none of which is a UIElement.

Comment: lol, Geometry is a WPF class. Okay, done splitting hairs.  Good day to you, sir.

Comment: @Will Sure it is, like many other WPF types commonly found in view models, e.g. Color, Brush, ImageSource, Transform, or any other type that a view property can sensibly be bound to.

Comment: The library i am using is generating the Path elements. How is extracting the geometry from those Path objects into this second class and then recreating the class in the UI any different then just adding the pre-generated ones directly to the UI?

Comment: @CameronHurst The problem with directly using generated Path elements in a view model is that they could only be used in one view at a time. A Visual can only be the child of one parent Visual. So you couldn't have more than one view binding to that view model. You may however probably create VisualBrushes from the generated Paths, and thus enable multiple views to use them.

Comment: @Clemens the library I am using is used to render DXF's. Supports GDI, OpenGL and WPF. They do a lot of work to handle the rendering all the different types of shapes and objects that could occur. If I was to extract the geometry from the generated paths, and then in the viewmodel create a RenderTransform on the canvas. Would that be an appropriate method to handle manipulating the graphics?

Comment: Not sure why you would need a RenderTransform. Aren't there absolute coordinates in the Paths' geometries? Maybe you add some details about the generated Paths to your question.

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>` Yeah, you can stop there.  That isn't MVVM.  Also, you define the item template as a (blank, I guess you could say) path object.  You do NOT bind that to the properties of the Paths you throw in your observable collection.

A better implementation would be to have an `ObservableCollection<string>` containing path ***data***, AKA [the stuff that actually defines the path's shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data(v=vs.110).aspx), then bind *this* to your path.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you had used Snoop to examine your UI at runtime, you'd have seen that you had lots of Path objects out there, but that they all had empty data.

Also ALSO, if you're using a canvas for the Path shapes, you need to set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties on your Paths.  A true MVVM hero would define a model thusly

```
public PathData{
    public double Left {get;set;}
    public double Top {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

then expose these in your ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<PathData> Items {get;private set;}
```

*then* bind your Path to them

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Path Canvas.Left="{Binding Left}"
              Canvas.Top="{Binding Top}"
              Data="{Binding Data}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Why set Left and Top when Data already contains the final corrdinates? A Canvas makes perfect sense without Left and Top, because it doesn't scale or translate its children.

Comment: @Clemens Do they?  Or are they all going to be rendered with an origin of 0,0 in the canvas?  Why a canvas if you're not using the canvas to control the position of your items?

Comment: You are controlling the positions by the Geometry in the Data property. E.g. an EllipseGeometry with Center at (100, 100). That isn't rendered at (0, 0), right?

Comment: @Clemens you're making an assumption about what he is trying to do?  I'm not.  In my example, I'm using the *Data* value prior to conversion, i.e. text that is in **svg** format (or closely related to it). You're talking about what that svg gets converted into.

Comment: Your assumption is that each Data is relative to a certain position specified by Left and Top, my assumption is that each Data is relative to (0, 0). IMO the latter is simpler, and it is what OP was trying to do. And Data should of course not be a string, but a Geometry. This isn't SVG, it's WPF.

Comment: @Clemens OP is creating Path objects in his ViewModel, so all bets are off.  I'm keeping this very simple--here is your shape data in a very common format used in WPF. Here is your transform in the standard model (left, top). Bind them to your Path and you're done. I've done it many times before. And it doesn't require you create a Path with any kind of Geometries in your view model.

Comment: You could easily create a Geometry from a string at runtime by [Geometry.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.parse.aspx). However, you won't be able to easily create an ellipse with a path markup string.

Comment: @Will can you explain _why_ this isn't MVVM?

Comment: @Segfault Creating UI in the ViewModel is a big hint.