# Generically draw shapes on a canvas through a single collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I’m tying to generically draw an ObservableCollection of System.Windows.Shapes.Shape on a canvas using an ItemsControl but I am not sure about how to write the XAML to do it properly.

I've seen many posts regarding this topic, but they all seem to be tied to specific shape types.  For example, from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026193/bind-collection-of-lines-to-canvas-in-wpf) I realize I could  define an ItemsContainer and set its template to draw lines, circles, etc.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}"
                  X2="{Binding To.X}" Y2="{Binding To.Y}"
                  Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeThickness="3"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But this requires me to expose my shapes as separately typed collections of lines, circles, etc.  -- or at least write some sort of filtering properties that do that.  I was hoping to just expose just one collection of shapes.  (I will be adding new shape types later on and don't want to have to keep adding new collection properties)

1. Is there a simple, "best" approach I can take to achieve this without exposing separate collection types?
2. Should I be looking at ItemTemplateSelector?  It seems to me that would have the same problem of needing specific shape types.
3. Some other approach?

Comment: Why can't you have one collection of a common base class, with implicit datatemplates for the various subclasses? Or just use Paths for everything.

Comment: The paths thing is a good alternative, thanks.  But as for one collection of a common base class, that's what I have now.   But I don't understand how I can use datatemplates with that.  Data templates are based on the target type, right?  So if all it gets is a base class reference, how can data template selection work?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding data templates?

Comment: The datatemplate is selected based on the actual runtime type of the object. It's all reflection. That's what's so powerful about WPF. Everything in WPF takes Object, non-generic IList, etc., and then figures out what it really is.

Comment: Ah.  Of course.  I think I've spent way too many years in C++.   I keep thinking that all types are hard-bound at build-time.  Thank you.

Comment: C++ has RTTI doesn't it?

Comment: It does.  But its use usually indicates poor design.  And its generics are still hard-bound at compile time.  The ability to dynamic cast is not the same thing as reflection

Comment: True. And the same design principles apply in C#. I don't think generics are all that different though, at least in the respect you mention, if I understand you.

Comment: The difference (which I clearly missed by posting this question) is that generics are resolved at run time, not build time.  Different language, different goals.  Both awesome

Comment: You shouldn't have UIElements in your source collection. Better use a Geometry to define a shape, and a Path element in the ItemTemplate, as e.g. shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30766339/1136211

Comment: Generics are resolved at compile time in C#.

Comment: They are?  Then how does this MSDN article (comparing c++ templates with generics) not contradict that?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/branbray/2003/11/19/templates-and-generics/

Comment: @Clemens I don't think anbody's suggesting putting ui elements anywhere but in the template. I sure hope not.

Comment: You have both been very helpful, thank you.  I'll admit I still don't quite "grok" C# generics -- I keep trying to force them into my C++ mindset.  But I'll get it eventually

Comment: If you want your models to be all the same type and be able to, at runtime, determine the template to use based on a property or attribute of an instance, you'll have to create a custom DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: @Ed I wasn't referring to any suggestion made in a comment, just to "ObservableCollection of System.Windows.Shapes.Shape" from the question.

Comment: @Clemens Whoops, I totally missed that! Derp. Thanks.